# How can I pass-on to a Function a newly created Object of ManagedObject of a Data Model?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am writing an IOS App which receives data from the user which I want to store in two different data models with different purposes:

1. in a temporary data model (= ReconciliationModel) to syncronize with the webserver once the device has a running internet connection and
2. in a functional data model (= ProgramModel) which is the basis for the ViewController and the App beeing able to operate.

I want the User to be able to work without an internet connection.

Therefore I am trying to pass-on a newly created instance of the Reconciliation-ManagedObject (=reconTask) after it has been saved to a 2nd function (= apiCheckCodes). Unfortunately this is not working and I am thankful for any help. This is the code:

```
`func setReconciliationList()->Void {
    let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("ReconciliationModel", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
    let reconTask = ReconciliationModel(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
    reconTask.reconStatus = false
    reconTask.reconType = 2
    reconTask.reconUser = inputTextField.User
    appDelegate.saveContext()    
    // if Internet available ...
    redeemCodes(reconTask.managedObjectContext!)
}`

func apiCheckCodes(context: context: NSManagedObjectContext)-> Void {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ReconciliationModel")
    var requestError: NSError?
    let response = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &requestError) as [ReconciliationModel!]
    let reconObject = (response as NSArray).lastObject as ReconciliationModel

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:3000/apicodecheck")!)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var params = [
    "user" : ReconObject.user,
    "status" : ReconObject.status,
    "programGoal" : String(ReconObject.programGoal)
    ]
    var error: NSError?
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &error)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    // API Redeem Post request
    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, err) -> Void in
        var conversionError: NSError?
        var jsonDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: &conversionError) as? NSDictionary
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Edit:
I found a way around it with a fetchRequest in the 2nd function (see above). Is this the only solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was doing wrong and therefore the work-around solution I described in my edit above with fetchRequest is no longer needed.

I was defining the 2nd function (= apiCheckCodes) wrongly with "as ReconciliationModel" instead of like this:

```
func verifiyScannedCode(reconObject: ReconciliationModel) {...}
```

Now I can call the this function with the newly created ManagedObject as a Parameter

```
verifiyScannedCode(reconTask)
```